# Backspace and Delete not registering in blessed terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, terminal

I am messing around with the [blessed](https://pypi.org/project/blessed/) library, and I found [this basic text editor program](https://github.com/jquast/blessed/blob/master/bin/editor.py).  When I run it in my terminal, all of the keys register except for backspace and delete.  Inside the program is a function that checks the key inputs:

```
def readline(term, width=20):
    """A rudimentary readline implementation."""
    text = u''
    while True:

        inp = term.inkey()
        if inp.code == term.KEY_ENTER:
            break
        elif inp.code == term.KEY_ESCAPE or inp == chr(3):
            text = None
            break
        elif not inp.is_sequence and len(text) < width:
            text += inp
            echo(inp)
        elif inp.code in (term.KEY_BACKSPACE, term.KEY_DELETE):
            text = text[:-1]
            # https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/HowUnixBackspaces
            #
            # "When you hit backspace, the kernel tty line discipline rubs out
            # your previous character by printing (in the simple case)
            # Ctrl-H, a space, and then another Ctrl-H."
            echo(u'\b \b')
    return text
```

Which includes `KEY_BACKSPACE` and `KEY_DELETE`.  I checked the documentation and ran a program to check the keys myself, and those are the correct names on my device.  I am just unsure why all the other keys work except for those?  I am on Windows 10 using the default CMD and Python 3.10 if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: @Stuuuve I had the same question as you and ended up here! Hopefully my findings will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've pasted in your question is for saving to a file. If you try using backspace when entering the file name, you'll see that it works.

You can find this in [the main loop](https://github.com/jquast/blessed/blob/master/bin/editor.py#L232-L271) under the logic for Ctrl + S. Notice also that there is no logic here for BACKSPACE or DELETE.

```
def main():
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        inp = term.inkey()

        if inp == chr(3):
            # ^c exits
            break

        elif inp == chr(19):
            # ^s saves
            ...
            save(screen, readline(term))
            ...
            continue
        ...
        else:
            ...
        ...
```